# Issue with Facebook Authorization in Qt IOS without using Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, qt, facebook, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to implement Facebook authorization in my Qt application without using the Facebook iOS SDK. After successfully obtaining the authorization code, I attempt to exchange it for a JWT token by making a request to *https://example.com/api/check-facebook*. However, I encounter the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 36008,
        "fbtrace_id": "A2W3BEDO9mLJDcFmzElHkBD"
    }
}
```

I have added the URL *https://example.com/api/check-facebook* to the list of valid redirect URIs for OAuth, and it passes the testing.

Here is a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
Application::Application(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{
    QDesktopServices::setUrlHandler(QString("fb%1").arg(FACEBOOK_CLIENT_IDENTIFIER), this, "facebook");
}

void Application::loginViaFacebook()
{
    QUrl url("fbauth2://authorize");
    QUrlQuery query;
    query.addQueryItem("client_id", FACEBOOK_CLIENT_IDENTIFIER);
    query.addQueryItem("redirect_uri", QUrl::toPercentEncoding("https://example.com/api/check-facebook"));
    query.addQueryItem("scope", QStringList{"public_profile", "email"}.join(","));
    query.addQueryItem("response_type", QUrl::toPercentEncoding(QStringList{"code", "token"}.join(" ")));
    url.setQuery(query);
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(url);
}

void Application::facebook(const QUrl &url)
{
    QUrlQuery urlQuery(url.fragment());
    if (!urlQuery.hasQueryItem("code"))
        return;

    QUrl requestUrl("https://example.com/api/check-facebook");
    QUrlQuery query;
    query.addQueryItem("code", urlQuery.queryItemValue("code"));
    requestUrl.setQuery(query);

    auto manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    auto reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(requestUrl));
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, [=]{
        setError(reply->readAll());

        reply->deleteLater();
        manager->deleteLater();
    });
}
```

I suspect there might be an issue with how I'm handling the redirect URI or the authorization code exchange. Can someone please guide me on what might be causing this error?

Thank you!